# $(a_{1},a_{2})$ and $(b_{1},b_{2})\in \mathbb{Z}^{2}$ with certain property

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we find $(a_{1},a_{2})$ and $(b_{1},b_{2})\in \mathbb{Z}^{2}$ such that $$a_{1}a_{2} - 6\cdot b_{1}b_{2} = 2$$ and $$a_{1}b_{2}+a_{2}b_{1} = 1$$ 
$\textbf{Note.}$ $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2} \neq 0$.

Comment: Did you try something? Any kind of manipulations?

Comment: @Winther these are non zero

Comment: @Winther, I am sorry but $b_1=-2$ and $b_2=1$ lead to a non-integer  (and even complex) solution

Comment: @JeanMarie That is true, my code had a bug, I used $a_2=a_1$ in the last equation. Fixing this I don't find any non-zero solutions with $a_i,b_i$ in $[-40,40]$.

Comment: I agree : the results of my solution show that necessarily $b_1$ should be $0$...

Comment: For reference the solutions I find with $a_i,b_i$ in $[-50,50]$ are: $(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2) = (-2 ,-1, -1, 0)$ , $(-1, -2, 0, -1)$ , $(1, 2, 0, 1)$ and $(2, 1, 1, 0)$.

Comment: No news from you, Inve ?

Comment: @Winther Yes, and in all cases one of the values is $0$...

Comment: @Winther I have provided a full solution where I find back the particular cases (non of them valid due to the non-nullity solution) you mentionned.

Answer (score 3):

The given system can be considered as a linear system with parameters $a_1$ and $b_1$, and thus solved in the following way

$$a_2= 2\dfrac{a_1 + 3b_1}{a_1^2 + 6 b_1^2}, \ \ \ b_2= \dfrac{a_1 - 2b_1}{a_1^2 + 6b_1^2}$$

These rational numbers have to be integers.

In particular $a_2-2b_2=\dfrac{10b_1}{a_1^2 + 6 b_1^2}$ should be an integer.

In other words, there should exist $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$k(a_1^2 + 6 b_1^2)=10 b_1 \ \ \ (1)$$

As $a_1^2>0$, the absolute value of the LHS is $>6|k|b_1^2$. Thus, if there is a solution, it is with $|k|=1$ and $|b_1|=1$ (otherwise the abs. value of the LHS of (1) would be $>12|b_1|$, which is not compatible with the RHS).
Equation (1) then becomes

$$a_1^2 +6 = +10 \ \ \ \ (2)$$

or $a_1^2 +6 = -10$ (this last case being without solution).

A consequence of (2) is that $|a_1|=2$.

Plugging these values of $(a_1,b_1)=(2,1)$ or $(-2,1)$, or $(2,-1)$ or $(-2,-1)$ into the expressions of $x$ and $y$ above give no valid solution (either $b_2=0$, or $x$ not integer, or $y=0$, resp. ).

As a conclusion, there are no solutions for which $a_1a_2b_1b_2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Added, at the end, the rest of the solution.

Comment: I am almost sure that considering your conditions as [GCD conditions : see Bezout identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) may simplify the proof.

Comment: the first displayed equation, second part, should be $a_1 y + b_1 x = 1$ rather than the current $a_1 y + a_2 x = 1$

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I have corrected it : happily, it had no influence on the rest.